# Apache2 server/website stops responding while download is in progress

Tags: php, mysql, web, timeout, apache2

I have a quite peculiar problem.
I have a website that is running on a ubuntu server under Apache2.4.
The site is written in PHP and uses MySQL as a database.
I have realised "file storage" for small files in the MySQL database as longblobs.

When I want to download a blob/file from the MySQL database, I open a PDO connection to the database.

```
$sql = $pdoData->prepare("SELECT * FROM fileblob WHERE ID = ?");
$sql->execute(array($blobID));
$row = $sql->fetch();
$content = $row['data'];
```

via "echo $content" I then transmit the file to the browser.
All of this works flawlessly. However. During the download the whole site stops responding, every new request runs into a timeout.
The download is continuing fine.

When the download gets to 4MB remaining, the website starts functioning again, but very slowly. When it is finished, the site is completely back to normal.

The MySQL database uses an InnoDB backend, has a maximum of 500 concurrent connections etc.

During the time of the download there are only 6 open SQL connections. 
Disk usage is at max at around 20%,CPU usage under 10%
Apache is also set up to handle 1k concurrent connections (10 threads with 100 children at max). The server is connected via an unmetered 1Gbps line.
I can not think of any hardware bottleneck.

What am I missing?
I am happy to answer any questions...

Comment: What's your output buffering setting? Are you using PHP sessions in your scripts?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I am using PHP sessions literally everywhere. Output buffer is set to 4096

Comment: _"Output buffer is set to 4096"_ - well that could explain why you see the effect changing at around 4MB ... try disabling it for this request/part of the script. Also, use session_write_close as soon as you are done with the session - otherwise, file locking on the session data file can also keep concurrent requests "hanging".

Comment: @CBroe OK, I'll try that. However, I though that 4096 means 4kbytes...

Comment: Right, my bad, 4096 would be 4KB, not MB ... but check on the session issue, that's a common cause for having scripts appear to "hang" in such a situation.

Comment: @CBroe OK, new insights. While I am downloading a blob, I also cannot access simple HTML pages. Looks to me like Apache is fucking something up. I tohugh I configured it for 1000 concurrent connections...

Comment: @CBroe session_write_close was the answer! Everything works now. Would you mind posting that as the answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using PHP's default file-based session mechanism, PHP locks the session data file while any script accessing that specific session is running.

So while your download is running, the session data file is kept open all the while, and any other scripts are prevented from accessing the same session - they will simply have to wait, until the file lock is released again.

To help prevent that, [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) can be used. It tells PHP that the current script is done with manipulating the session data, so that the session content can be written to the data file now, and the file lock released, so that other scripts can access it again.

(You obviously need to be done with your session data manipulation at this point; you can not change session contents again in that same script afterwards.)